# Using a pointer to dynamically allocate Matrices in c++ in presence of eigen library

Tags: c++, pointers, eigen, dynamic-memory-allocation

I use Eigen library to initialize matrices and do calculations related to diagonalization and such. Till now, I have been using 'call by value' method, i.e. :

1. I define a a complex double NxN matrix with MatrixXcd H(N,N).
2. Then I call a routine like SelfAdjointMatrixSolver es(H).
3. Finally I obtain the eigenvalues with es.eigenvalues().

Now, I would like to dynamically allocate matrices using pointer. I wrote the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<Eigen/Dense>
#include<fstream>
#include<random>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;



int main()
 {
 int i,j,k,l;//for loops
 MatrixXd *H = NULL;
 H = new MatrixXd(10,10);
 if (!H) 
 cout << "allocation of memory failed\n"; 
 else
 {
 for(i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
   for(j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
     H[i][j]=1.0;
    }
  }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

I get the following error messages :

```
In file included from eigen/Eigen/Core:347:0,
                 from eigen/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from test.cpp:7:
eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h: In instantiation of ‘Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Derived, 1>::Scalar& Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Derived, 1>::operator[](Eigen::Index) [with Derived = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>; Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Derived, 1>::Scalar = double; Eigen::Index = long int]’:
test.cpp:32:13:   required from here
eigen/Eigen/src/Core/util/StaticAssert.h:32:40: error: static assertion failed: THE_BRACKET_OPERATOR_IS_ONLY_FOR_VECTORS__USE_THE_PARENTHESIS_OPERATOR_INSTEAD
     #define EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT(X,MSG) static_assert(X,#MSG);
                                        ^
eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:406:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT’
       EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT(Derived::IsVectorAtCompileTime,
```

How should I solve this problem? Is my mistake is in defining the pointer or in assigning the values?

Comment: The variable `H` isn't a `MatrixXd` object, but `*H` is. Try using `(*H)[i][j]`.

Comment: So this seems to be working, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

As this assertion says `THE_BRACKET_OPERATOR_IS_ONLY_FOR_VECTORS__USE_THE_PARENTHESIS_OPERATOR_INSTEAD` the matrix class uses parentheses to index, not square braces [as noted in the docs](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html). So change

```
H[i][j] = 1.0;
```

to

```
H(i,j) = 1.0;
```

Also the matrix is already dynamically allocated, no need for `new` here.

```
MatrixXd H(10, 10);
```

Comment: So I previously used to do that. But I now want to take a pointer approach, because I have to diagonalize a 2744 x 2744 matrix, obtain the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, calculate a particular quantity from the eigenvectors. And I have to iterate this process for 300-400 times.

Till now I have done this procedure with a 512 x 512 matrix, it took 2-3 hours. but with 2744 x 2744 matrix, it has been going on for 20-22 hours. So how can I dynamically allocate and free the memory so the process becomes faster?

Comment: The matrix class *already dynamically allocates* the underlying array it manages. Allocating your matrix with `new` will not make your computation any faster, I promise.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is there any way I can free the memory taken by the Hamiltonian once it's used? Like how we use free() in c or delete[] in c++, is there any such equivalent thing for eigen defined matrices?

Comment: You should be able to just do `H.resize(0,0)` to clear it

Comment: @sap7889 Did you compile with optimizations enabled? Allocating `MatrixXd` with `new` will not help at all here.

Comment: @chtz No I haven't compiled with optimizations enabled, sorry. but I have a feeling if I can free the memory after each iteration, that might help, hence I posed the questions. Cory Kramer and Some programmer dude's ideas might help me, so I am checking those out.

Comment: You should rather avoid allocation/deallocation of memory inside your inner loop, if possible. But not enabling optimization will be the main reason for slow Eigen performance (cf. http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=FAQ#How_do_I_get_good_performance.3F)

Comment: How do I enable optimization? Sorry, I am not too much experienced. I compile with mpiCC -I eigen -std=c++11 filename.cpp, do I need to change it?

Comment: Add `-O3` for example to enable optimizations, you can read more about that [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)